# How to react with movement

Tags: ruby, terminal

I'm thinking about writing a little game for terminal in ruby, something like pong. I don't know how to imitate movement in terminal. What ways would you recommend to solve this problem? We have letter "A" displayed on the bottom, and we want it to move up for 'w' and down for 's' without pressing 'enter'. I don't expect everything to be written for me, just general description, methods names etc.

Answer (score 2):

### Basic Options for Terminals and Widgets

For something simple, you can use:

- The [curses module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html) from the Ruby Standard Library.
- The terminal's [tput](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) utility, if supported and available.
- The canvas widget from [Ruby/Tk](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_canvas.htm) or other similar framework.

There are doubtless other gems and frameworks available, but the short list above should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of *great* libraries, especially ones that are going to be cross-platform.  I would look at curses/ncurses.

Ruby has a built in class for working with Curses: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html

It's a fairly copy-and-paste implementation of the C library, so don't expect a lot of Objects or elegant ruby code.